# Using PHP variable in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm having some trouble using a variable declared in PHP with an SQL query. I have used the resources at [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement) but have had no luck with them. I realize this is prone to SQL injection and if someone wants to show me how to protect against that, I will gladly implement that. (I think by using mysql_real_escape_string but that may be deprecated?)

```
<?php
$q = 'Hospital_Name';
$query = "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE field_name = 'hospital_name' AND value = '$q'";

$query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
   echo $row['value'];
}
?>
```

I have tried switching `'$q'` with `$q` and that doesn't work. If I substitute the hospital name directly into the query, the SQL query and PHP output code works so I know that's not the problem unless for some reason it uses different logic with a variable when connecting to the database and executing the query.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I'll go ahead and post more of my actual code instead of just the problem areas since unfortunately none of the answers provided have worked. I am trying to print out a "Case ID" that is the primary key tied to a patient. I am using a REDCap clinical database and their table structure is a little different than normal relational databases. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$q = 'Hospital_Name';
$query = "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE field_name = 'case_id' AND record in (SELECT distinct record FROM database.table WHERE field_name = 'hospital_name' AND value = '$q')";

$query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
   echo $row['value'];
}
?>
```

I have tried substituting `$q` with `'$q'` and `'".$q."'` and none of those print out the case_id that I need. I also tried using the `mysqli_stmt_*` functions but they printed nothing but blank as well. Our server uses PHP version 5.3.3 if that is helpful.

Thanks again.

Comment: you have a stray bracket in this `'$q')";`  so where is `(` ? Edit: as per https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44396690/1

Comment: Define "i'm having some trouble" and  "doesn't work"

Comment: If I type in the name of the hospital, it outputs what I want, and if I use a variable, it outputs nothing.

Comment: *"because when I substitute in the hospital name it works"* - which is what *exactly?* and I mean... "exactly". As in `St-Mary` or `St-mary` or `Saint Mary's`? it matters you know.

Comment: someone gave you an answer btw; try that.

Comment: `WHERE field_name = 'hospital_name' AND value = '$q'` both conditions must be met and perfectly. My above comment was edited btw. You may have to include real values from your db.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like so

```
<?php
$q = 'mercy_west';
$query = "SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM database.table WHERE field_name = 'hospital_name' AND value = ?";
if($stmt = $db->query($query)){
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$q);   // s is for string, i for integer, number of these must match your ? marks in query. Then variable you're binding is the $q, Must match number of ? as well
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4);  // Can initialize these above with $col1 = "", but these bind what you're selecting. If you select 5 times, must have 5 variables, and they go in in order. select id,name, bind_result($id,name)
  $stmt->store_result();
  while($stmt->fetch()){   // fetch the results
    echo $col1;
  }
  $stmt->close();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is deprecated.

One solution, as hinted by answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193980/1575353) in that post you included a link to, is to use prepared statements. MySQLi and PDO both support binding parameters with prepared statements.

To continue using the mysqli_* functions, use:

- [mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) to get a prepared statement
- [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind the parameter (e.g. for the *WHERE* condition `value='$q'`)
- [mysqli_stmt_execute()](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_execute) to execute the statement
- [mysqli_stmt_bind_result()](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_result) to send the output to a variable.

  ```
  <?php
  $q = 'Hospital_Name';
  $query = "SELECT value FROM database.table WHERE field_name = 'hospital_name' AND value = ?";

  $statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);

  //Bind parameter for $q; substituted for first ? in $query
  //first parameter: 's' -> string
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 's', $q); 

  //execute the statement
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

  //bind an output variable
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $value);

  while ( mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      echo $value; //print the value from each returned row
  }
  ```

If you consider using PDO, look at [bindparam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). You will need to determine the parameters for the [PDO constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) but then can use it to get prepared statements with the [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method.